# leet15, 3Sum, question about the condition

Tags: python

The question is below:
Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and `nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0`.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

```
class Solution:
def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    n = len(nums)
    nums.sort()
    ans = list()
    
    
    for first in range(n):
        
        if first > 0 and nums[first] == nums[first - 1]:
            continue
        
        third = n - 1
        target = -nums[first]
        
        for second in range(first + 1, n):
            
            if second > first + 1 and nums[second] == nums[second - 1]:
                continue
            
            while second < third and nums[second] + nums[third] > target:
                third -= 1
            
            
            if second == third:
                break
            if nums[second] + nums[third] == target:
                ans.append([nums[first], nums[second], nums[third]])
    
    return ans
```

In this solution, I don't know why the condition  `if first > 0 and nums[first] == nums[first - 1]:`, why it shoudl be less than 0, not `first != 0`?

Because when we traversal  n, it should start from 0, right? so it cannot be negative, only 0 or positive.

Comment: The possible reason for that checking is to confirm the `nums` list has more elements.

Comment: but why it cannot be "if first != 0"?